# Profile is not getting created for the new user after extension of the user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Before extending the user module, I was easily able to register new users and the page would get redirected to the login page. Now on registering new users, the profile is not getting created and the page is also not getting redirected. The new user does get created though and sometimes the error is object does not exist, user profile does not exist, and sometimes the error is forbidden, csrf verification failed. I dont know where I'm going wrong. existing users are able to login and update profiles but new users I'm having a problem with.

Models.py is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null= True ,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null = True, blank= True)
    first = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null= True)
    postal = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first
```

My forms.py is:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, fields
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password2 = None
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name', 'last_name','email', 'password1']

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
        widgets = {
            'profile_pic': forms.FileInput()
        }
```

views.py is (I removed the login and logout view cause that was working fine):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm, ProfileForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import *

def RegisterPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('Profile')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
                messages.success(request, 'Account created for ' + name)
                Profile.object.create(
                    user = user,
                )
                Profile.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Login/')
        else:
            form = CreateUserForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='Login')
def Profile(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

my register template:

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Username*</strong></p>
            <div class="forms">{{form.username}}</div>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>First Name*</strong></p>
            <div class="forms">{{form.first_name}}</div>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Last Name*</strong></p>
            <div class="forms">{{form.last_name}}</div>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Email-ID*</strong></p>
            <div class="forms">{{form.email}}</div>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Password*</strong></p>
            <div class="forms">{{form.password1}}</div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg col-lg-10 reg-btn">Register</button>
        </form>
```

My login template:

```
<p class="login-reg">New to MedsPlain? <a class="log-reg-link" href="/Registration/">Register </a>here</p>
        <hr> {% if next %}
        <form class="" action='/Login/Profile/' method="post"> {% csrf_token %} {%else%}
            <form class="" action="/Login/" method="post">
                {% endif %} {% csrf_token %}
                <p class="login-field-title"><strong>Username*</strong></p>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="Enter Username" required>

                <p class="login-field-title"><strong>Password*</strong></p>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="Enter Password" required> {% for message in messages %}
                <p id="messages">{{message}}</p>
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg col-lg-10 log-btn">Log In</button>
            </form>
```

I've tried everything as of now, but i don't understand the mistake. Can someone please guide me through cause at this moment i'm frustrated, on the verge of crying and don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two problems here:

1. there is a view `Profile`, and thus this will override the reference to the `Profile` model; and
2. you do not create a model record with `Model.object.create()`, but with `Model.objects.create()`.

I would advise that you rename your views in `snake_case`, and *remove* the *wildcard* import, this is often *not* a good idea:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm, ProfileForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Profile

def register_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('Profile')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                Profile.objects.create(
                    user = user,
                )
                messages.success(request, 'Account created for {user.first_name}')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Login/')
        else:
            form = CreateUserForm()
        context = {'form': form }
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='Login')
def profile(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

You will also need to update the `urls.py` to work with the renamed views.

Comment: Thank You so much. This did solve a lot of my problems